# Controllers em subpastas CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Gostaria de saber como eu posso colocar controllers em subpastas no Cake? Eu fiz a seguinte alteração no bootstrap.php mas não deu certo:

```
     App::build(array(
     'Controller' => array(
          ROOT . 'app/Controller/Admin/'
     )
 ));
```

Ou seja, dentro da pasta Controller, tenho uma pasta chamada Admin. Destro dessa pasta, criei um Controller chamado AdmController e criei uma função lá para testes chamada teste, só que não funciona. Eu coloquei no navegador o caminho:

```
http://localhost/cake/admin/adm/teste
```

e diz que tenho que criar o AdminController dentro da pasta Controller

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Obrigado

Comment: Não está funcionando porque você está pedindo o `App::build()` do controller na pasta `admin`, no caso, AdminController, precisa adicionar o `adm` no final da string.

Answer (score 2):

Tente desta forma:

```
App::build(array(
     'Controller' => array(
          ROOT . 'app/Controller/Admin/Adm/'
     )
));
```

Também existe a possibilidade de usar um plugin para fazer isto automaticamente:
https://github.com/ichikaway/AutoAppBuild#

Mas a forma correta de se fazer isto no cakephp, seria com prefixos, assim você mantem a estrutura original e obtém um prefixo `/admin` ou outro qualquer para a sua aplicação.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing